# Handling Rich Text in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, richtext

What are the best practices regarding working with rich text in a web application?  I don't want to leave myself vulnerable to script attacks.  Should the data be encoded going into the database and then decoded when displayed back to the user?  Any advice on rich text editor's that handle things like removing script tags or encoding the entered markup?

Comment: You didn't address the encoding/decoding or the text editor portion of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pick a whitelist of known tags and attributes, parse the user input as XML, and remove every tag or attribute that isn't in the whitelist.

**EDIT**: Note that if you allow hyperlinks or images, you have to validate the `src` and `href` tags.  I would recommend parsing it using `System.Uri`, restricting the scheme to `http`, and perhaps the domain to your site (depending what you want your users to be able to do).

Similar things have been done before; google them.

**EDIT**: For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551480/writing-xss-filter-for-xhtml-based-on-white-list)

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> EDIT**:

You should not encode the data before putting it into the database.  As long as you're using parameters (and if you aren't, you **really** should), the database will be completely unaffected by anything you put in it.

If your input sanitization is secure (see above), it won't make any difference if you encode it and decode it on the way, and if the sanitization isn't secure, encoding it won't help.

However, it probably is a good idea to run it through a standard XML parser, reject any input that doesn't parse, and use the formatted XML from the parser (as I mentioned above)

---

**3<sup>rd</sup> EDIT**:

There are many rich text editors out there; for MVC, I think I'd recommend [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/).  It will escape input for you, but you **must** not rely on it exclusively as an attacker can disable JavaScript or forge his own HTTP request.  (You still need to validate the HTML on the server).  There are many rich editors for web forms (which, I assume, do server-side validation); there aren't any for MVC (yet)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to encode data which is send to user and do not encode it in database.Also far as I know asp.net prevent script attacks by validating input.

Comment: If you encode it on the way out wouldn't it not display as rich text?